# python request post is executed just onetime in loop

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to execute below function in loop

```
def post_webhook(payload):                                                                                                                                    
  if not WEBHOOK_URL:                                                                                                                                         
    print "WEBHOOK_URL isn't setted"                                                                                                                          
    return                                                                                                                                                    
  try:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      json = {'data': payload}                                                                                                                                
      print "webhook_url:", WEBHOOK_URL                                                                                                                       
      r = requests.post(WEBHOOK_URL, data=json)                                                                                                               
      print "requests.post:", r.text                                                                                                                          
  except Exception as e:                                                                                                                                      
    print "post_webhook err:", e
```

like this

```
while True:
    post_webhook(payload)
```

But, post_webhook function is executed just onetime
and when I called post_webook() in while loop, `print "requests.post:", r.text` isn't executed in post_webhook()

as a result, `r = requests.post(WEBHOOK_URL, data=json)` is executed just onetime in loop, what I want to is to execute post_webhook() many times in loop

Why is request.post executed just onetime in loop?

Comment: One possible reason might be that your request hasn't yet completed. If this is the case then nothing should be printed out from `r.text`. If this is the case, then let it timeout and then it would again call the same method.

Comment: What happens after it prints one line of output?  Does it exit, or does it hang?

Comment: @hyades How can I let it timeout?

Comment: @1.618 not exit, it's hang

Comment: Just set `timeout=5` as one of the args. Refer http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts

Comment: @hyades oh, Thank you, I set timeout as argument then this function is worked nomally